# ASP.net Still cannot upload files over 80KB

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to process line by line a file that can be a few hundred kilobytes in length, but when I try to upload a file that is over 80KB in length I get an exception:

```
Object Disposted Exception: Cannot access a closed file.
```

The file is uploaded to a controller and passed on to an Async task like so:

```
public JsonResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase csvFile)
{
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();

        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {

            ProcessFile(csvFile);

            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
        });
        return Json(new {fileId = fileId});
}
```

This then processes the file

```
    public static void ProcessFile(HttpPostedFileBase csvFile) {

        Int32 lineCount = 0;
        StreamReader lineCounter = new StreamReader(csvFile.InputStream);

        while (lineCounter.ReadLine() != null) { // exception occurs here with lineCount still 0
            lineCount += 1;
        }
        //Continue processing
```

I understand that by default it will not accept files larger than 80KB, but I have added the following lines to my web.config:

```
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="30000000" requestLengthDiskThreshold="30000000" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" />
  </system.web>

    <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="30000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

But this does not change the outcome. It works fine with files all the way up to 79KB.

Is there something else I need to add?

### Update:

My solution was to save the file locally in App_Data, and pass in the file location instead of the actual file. As far as I can tell, there is still no reason why IIS did not accept files larger than 80KB, and fail as soon as I try to access it, while a 79KB file runs through fine. I have no third party libraries and no other process or code is trying to access the file

Comment: It looks like you have closed the `lineCounter` Stream and later on you tried accessing and reading this stream further which is not possible. Unfortunately this happens in the `//Continue processing` part of the snippet of your code which you haven't shown us. I would recommend you wrapping `IDisposable`  resources such as Streams and Streamreaders in `using` statements to further limit their scope.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. The continue processing part doesn't get reached at all because the exception happens when I first try to access the file. Additionally, I'd like to emphasize that this works perfectly with files under 80KB

Comment: The file is closed - your task is fired off asynchronously and the web request will end - and the input file stream will be closed. You need to await the task so that the request is open and the file stream stays open. Otherwise you have an asynchronous task happening after the request ends - trying to access a stream tied to the request.

Comment: It looks like there's some other part of your code (or a 3rd party component you might be using) which is reading the input file stream at the same time and closing it.

Comment: In addition to what I said above .. you could make your action `async` and simply `await` the task you're firing off. That's probably the easiest way.

Comment: Sorry, but this still doesn't quite explain why files under 80KB work fine, and precisely 80KB is the cutoff point which I know to be the default setting for VS/IIS

Comment: Are you sure its _precisely_ 80KB? If the task is quick enough to execute before the end of the request (or its just made purely synchronous due to how quick it is) then you wouldn't see this error. Perhaps your file size is helping determine that. Either way.. its a quick change to check the theory.

Comment: I have tested with a 79KB file which worked and an 81KB file which threw the error

Comment: I think this is more to code issues. Would you please to post your full codes?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. I was extending Asp.Net CMS Episerver class and wanted to send file attachments with email. By default Episerver sends a link that user needs to login and download. I tried everything from async calls and task waits. I got very strange exceptions and most importantly this one: cannot access closed file. I was quite sure that the file stream object was never disposed when I was accessing it.

The culprit was requestLengthDiskThreshold setting in web.config. The default size of requestLengthDiskThreshold is 80kb (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.100).aspx)

I updated the web.config as per below:

> httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1000000"
>   requestLengthDiskThreshold="10240" requestValidationMode="2.0"

And bang the problem goes away for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies with the way IIS handles file uploading. All files over 80Kb are [cached to disk](https://www.infoq.com/news/2010/05/ScaleUp), and with you attempting to read that stream from a thread outside of MVC request pipeline, you get that limit. I'm not absolutely sure what exactly IIS does with threads, but if you try to read that stream from withing the request thread, you should be fine and the caching is transparent. But as soon as you are trying to reach that stream outside of the request thread, you get the error.

Also see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.aspx#Anchor_4) for a bit more explanation. Specifically see [HttpRuntimeSection.RequestLengthDiskThreshold Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestlengthdiskthreshold.aspx) that defines amount of data to be held in memory before starting disk buffering - default value to that is 80kb.

Solution would be to copy the file somewhere and pass the file path to your thread for processing. Or copy the stream into byte-array and pass that to your thread.

Comment: Geez.. just looked at the date of the question. DUH!

Comment: I don't even work at this job anymore, someone else's problem now! Still helpful for anyone else finding this

Comment: @SeanForman yeah, somebody put a (not entirely correct) answer below and this came up in my feed. I should really check for question dates. And I did have exactly the same problem couple weeks back...